# Method canvas.drawcolor(color) not working on android 5.0

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a little problem, I'm trying to draw a color on canvas, i use

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
```

and then two circles using

```
canvas.drawCircle(width, height, radius, paint)
```

it works just fine when i run the app on my tablet (android 4.1) but when i run it on my phone (android 5.0) it seems it doesn't draw anything. 
I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you confirm you've uploaded the most up-to-date revision of your code? I get caught out by that when switching devices, sometimes. I usually do a manual uninstall of the application and then install again. (There's a chance you're loading up an older version, which would have a different package and menu shortcut etc.)

Comment: Yes, I surely did that !

Comment: Check your width , height and radius on the phone and make sure you're not drawing off the screen when you use the phone.

Comment: In paralel i've implemented a function that draws on my bitmap directly using bmp.setpixel . In this case it works , I really have no idea why doesn't  work with canvas.draw method ..

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the width or height, because when i draw using bitmap.setpixel it works so ..

Comment: It might help to paste the code for your drawing function into the question.

Comment: canvas = new Canvas(bmp); canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);